# Array of hashes, how to count the list of 'webpages' with most unique 'page' views?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, unique-key

I am trying to display the most unique page views in order, but am unsure how. i have the variable with data:

```
data = [{"help_page/1"=>"126.318.035.038"},
 {"contact"=>"184.123.665.067"},
 {"home"=>"184.123.665.067"},
 {"about/2"=>"444.701.448.104"},
 {"help_page/1"=>"929.398.951.889"},
 {"index"=>"444.701.448.104"},
 {"help_page/1"=>"722.247.931.582"},
 {"about"=>"061.945.150.735"},
 {"help_page/1"=>"646.865.545.408"},
 {"home"=>"235.313.352.950"},
 {"help_page/1"=>"543.910.244.929"},
 {"home"=>"316.433.849.805"},
 {"contact"=>"543.910.244.929"}]
```

i tried something like this:

```
data.sort_by {|k, v| -v.uniq.count}.collect{|k, v| "#{k}\t#{v.uniq.count} #{'unique views', v.uniq.count}"}
```

i am trying to get results somewhat similar to the below:

```
/help_page/1    XX unique views
/contact    XX unique views
/home   XX unique views
/index  XX unique views
/about/2    XX unique views
/about  XX unique views
```

but no success.

Comment: That array of hashes doesn't look like it's constructed correctly; It's unwieldy and awkward to use so I suspect this is an XY problem. See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)" If it was constructed more idiomatically it would be easier to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) is your friend, everything else below is just formatting the output.

```rb
data.group_by do |h|
  h.to_a.first.first
end.map do |k, v|
  [k, v.count]
end.sort_by(&:last).reverse.to_h
#⇒ {"help_page/1"=>5,
#   "home"=>3,
#   "contact"=>2,
#   "about"=>1,
#   "index"=>1,
#   "about/2"=>1}
```

Answer (score 3):

We can make use of the method [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally), new in v2.7, for this:

```
data.map { |h| h.keys.first }.
     tally.
     sort_by { |_,count| -count }.
     each { |k,v| puts "#{k}   #{v} unique views" }
```

displays:

```
help_page/1   5 unique views
home   3 unique views
contact   2 unique views
about   1 unique views
index   1 unique views
about/2   1 unique views
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = data.map { |h| h.keys.first }
  #=> ["help_page/1", "contact", "home", "about/2", "help_page/1",
  #    "index", "help_page/1", "about", "help_page/1", "home",
  #    "help_page/1", "home", "contact"] 
b = a.tally
  #=> {"help_page/1"=>5, "contact"=>2, "home"=>3, "about/2"=>1,
  #    "index"=>1, "about"=>1} 
c = b.sort_by { |_,count| -count }
  #=> [["help_page/1", 5], ["home", 3], ["contact", 2], ["about", 1],
  #    ["index", 1], ["about/2", 1]]
c.each { |k,v| puts "#{k}   #{v} unique views" }
  #=> <displays the results shown above>
```

Comment: Nice I like the idea of `tally`. Haven't installed 2.7 yet

Comment: @engineersmnky, there are rumors that a method `Enumerable#tally_by` is in the works, equivalent to `tally` with a block, which would allow us to here write `data.tally_by { |h| h.keys.first }`. Why wasn't `tally` given an optional block, you may well ask? That may be followed by `Enumerable#tally_ho`, for use in fox-hunting apps.

Comment: well then I certainly insist that `Enumerator#next` be aliased as `sally_forth`